# Nuget package restore issue in two different version

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

nuget restore working properly in nuget.exe version 3.4.4.132 but in 3.5 returns below error code

```
Failed to load msbuild Toolset
  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
An error occurred when executing task 'NugetRestore'.
Error: NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed on that machine?

Comment: I get the same problem and I have VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to the *msbuild.exe* in your path is version 3.5. MSBuild 3.5 does not have two .dll's that we are attempting to load dynamically ("*Microsoft.Build.dll* and *Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll*")

Please make sure NuGet.exe uses MSBuild 4.0 or higher. This can be done by making sure MSBuild 4.0 or higher is the first to resolve in your path or by passing the -msbuildversion option.

Check the following commands:

> MSBuild.exe /version
>
> Get-Command MSBuild.exe

Hope it helps.

Comment: i used -MsBuildVersion 4.0 arguments with nuget but same error reproduced .How do you mention ms build version 3.5?

Comment: I've got MSBuild 12 installed and I also see the problem.